# If someone keeps downvoting my old answers can I be answer banned?

Tags: support, answers, downvotes, post-ban, serial-voting

I have some old answers. For the last two days, I am seeing serial downvoting. No one is giving any comment to explain if there is a problem with the answer, just downvoting. I already read that the system will catch this kind of action and I have already flag one of my answer about this action.

Does this kind of behavior have any kind of effect to my account, like getting me banned?

[image: Old answers]

Comment: @CaldeiraG thanks  ,I already do some search and raise a flag my main answer is this kind of action effect my account.

Comment: "I already read that the system will catch this kind of action" No, not that kind of action. It can detect serial downvotes in one day, but fails if the votes are split to multiple days. In such case, flag any of your answer and explain the issue with as many details as you have, so mods know what you mean and what they need to look at.

Comment: Although the post-ban algorithm is secret, with 7k rep I don't believe there is any realistic chance of you getting post-banned.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that a single individual, through targeted downvoting, can cause you to be post banned. Not when you have 100s of answers, the vast majority of which have a positive score and are not deleted.

Comment: Furthermore, given that the reputation lost from those votes can be recovered easily with more positive contributions, I wouldn't worry too much about it even if it isn't reversed. Think about it, someone is engaging in a futile attempt at revenge instead of doing something productive. That's just sad for them.

Comment: @CaldeiraG the OP is not asking about what happened to their flag, they are asking about what effects the downvotes may have on their account without or before those votes are found to be targeted and reverted.

Comment: @Tom: the OP has already raised a flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Side note: I answered your question from the POV of someone having downvoted your answers. However, the downvotes you have received recently have been on *questions*. The same answer applies: you have a fairly positive record, nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Plus quite likely that *meta effect* from this post will be in your favor.

Comment: The emoji in the first comment here is triggering me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only effect that this kind of voting has on an account like yours is that you lose a little bit of reputation points.

The answer ban is not going to kick in here because your overall body of answers has been positively received; the majority have a non-negative score and have not been deleted. With hundreds of answers no single account can change that overall picture.

Targeted downvote campaigns are actually quite rare and the vast majority of voting users use voting (up and down) for the right reasons, and we [never require anyone to explain their vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). In the long term their votes easily drown out a single downvoter.

As for your flag: it was marked helpful because a moderator has asked the community management team to investigate the pattern further. That may or may not lead to invalidation of those downvotes, but if the votes are to be reverted it can take a few days to take effect. Sorry, we generally don’t give status updates when such investigations do not result in reversals.

However, if there is a single individual that is targeting your answers with downvotes and they continue to do so, chances that the votes are eventually reverted only increase! We take such cases very seriously.

Comment: "In the long term their votes easily drown out a single downvoter." For the site, yes. For an account, yes. For a single or a few low view answers or questions? Not so much.

Comment: Whoever serial-downvoted knew what they were doing, too... looks like they were doing about 2 or 3 votes a day so that their votes weren't auto-reversed for being serial voting. Once they investigate that the perpetrator really ought to be suspended for voting irregularities in my opinion. Serial-downvoting someone in the heat of the moment is one thing, doing it in such an obviously premeditated manner is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 8):

These downvotes seem to be targeted not at answers, but at questions.  I looked at the first three ([Asp.net textarea add empty string to the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704982/asp-net-textarea-add-empty-string-to-the-value), [Run NgFor directive without prefix with star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744573/run-ngfor-directive-without-prefix-with-star), [Reactive form valid property return false when form is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466641/reactive-form-valid-property-return-false-when-form-is-disabled)) and have to say these aren’t very good questions.  Nowhere near the worst of course, but far from what I would consider good questions.

The first is a simple misunderstanding of what is happening, which could be valuable if it was rewritten to remove the images and explain what was going on. The second could use an example of what you have tried, as it is, it’s basically a “write me some codes” question. And the third has the relevant code on another site.

I’ve ran into something similar in the past: if you use someone’s account as as your starting point for exploring SO, should you treat the questions differently from if you’d just found them independently?  I’ve generally answered that question as yes, because I don’t want to trip any serial voting bans.

Anyway, if I was you, I’d take the opportunity to curate my questions.  As for your actual question in this case: the only negative impact will be on your reputation, no posting ban.