# Microsoft Azure Customer Engineers Giving Low Quality Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

I am new to Azure machine learning service and trying to post questions on Stack Overflow to get some help around issues that I face.

The questions always get picked up by Azure Customer Engineers (according to their profile) who try to answer them. However, if you look a little deeper the answers are:

1. pretty generic (look at this documentation)
2. don't answer your question AT ALL
3. often off topic. I asked about Azure machine learning service dataset and got an answer for Azure data factory dataset which is COMPLETELY different.

I guess these don't get flagged as low-quality answers since on the surface they appear pretty legitimate but they are really of no use.

I have no course but to downvote them. What other actions should I be taking?

Some examples:

- [Azure Machine Learning Service writing to AzureDataLakeGen2Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73035114)
  [image]
- [azureml tabular dataset over azure gen2 datalake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990565)
  [image]
- [AzureML Authentication for registering datasets using azureml.core.dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72907796)
  [image]

Comment: *"I have no course but to downvote them. What other actions should I be taking ?"* Certainly downvoting; I note that only one of those answers has a downvote, so if they aren't helpful then downvoting is the right course. If the answer isn't an answer, then you should be flagging it as Not An Answer (NAA). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990565/2029983), for example, doesn't really feel like an answer; it starts by asking for clarification, and then effectively gives a link as the answer.

Comment: Ah! thank you. I kinda completely missed the flagging an answer :) . I always was under the impression that only questions could be flagged. make sense. I did flag it now

Comment: Note that I wouldn't say that the other 2 are NAA. There is a (big) difference between NAA and not useful/helpful. They are certainly attempting to answer, though not necessarily well.

Comment: Looking at a few of that users recent answers, a lot of them are very low quality. It seems more like they are treating [so] as a support desk, and often are linking to documentation rather than giving the answer in the post ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021416/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021662/2029983), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73018754/2029983) as a few examples). Not all their answers are like it, but it *might* warrant a custom mod flag. I would be interested to see a passing mod's opinion on  the matter though.

Comment: Without revealing too much info, I could only say that the mods and staff have noticed this issue. As a non-SO mod, I'd suggest doing the standard actions to low-quality/NAA answers, i.e. downvote and/or flag.

Comment: I've noticed an increase in these types of answers too. It is nice that these engineers are getting engaged but they don't seem to realise that StackOverflow has different expectations than social.msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: If I understand it correctly [the TOS may not allow that kind of account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309280/665544).

Comment: It depends if each *individual* in the [support] team have an account or not, @bad_coder . If each team member does, it would be allowed; though of course each account would be under the same rules that all of are and would be expected to meet the quality requirements. My concern would be that if these individuate creating low quality content they would simply have a new account created if they are answer banned

Comment: @Larnu all the examples given are of a single account.

Comment: Yes, but I don't get the vide of a multiple people on a single account from it, @bad_coder . That doesn't mean it's not, though. I haven't looked enough answers to be able to tell, but also I would expect that SO would have caught the account by now if it was being used by many users. I suspect it is, instead, one of many accounts in the same team.

Comment: @Larnu what's bothering me is that account uses bold too much, if they write all their posts like in the Q's 1st link it's annoying. (Is there any rule against abusing bold?)

Comment: Emphasis misuse is an entirely different problem, @bad_coder . Though not what this is about, I generally edit such misuse out when I encounter such posts during normal use of the site (I haven't here, as I'm not really counting this "encounter" as normal usage).

Comment: [Is this formatting overuse?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362515/is-this-formatting-overuse) @bad_coder , for some more conanical posts.

Comment: I don't see any answers on the example questions you linked, guess those answers were deleted in the meantime?

Comment: I encountered similar users with "-MSFT" as an extension to their name posting mainly link-only answers. I collected a few of those to establish a pattern and mod flagged one of them to have a mod send them a message to adhere to the rules.

Comment: @Jérémy looks like meta effect has deleted those answers

Comment: I'm glad they cannot mark each others low quality answers as accepted/helpful, as they did on TechNet...

Comment: Appreciate this issue being raised and the efforts being made to quash the distracting vague and wrong/off-topic 'answers' routinely left by the Microsoft crew. It's deplorable that for years now Microsoft has allowed (encouraged?) its staff to give generic, "reinstall the drivers" type answers that waste everyone's time — social.msdn.microsoft.com is only worth consulting to see what other users have contributed, and it's nasty to have to wade through the lengthy and re-quoted but bad staff answers.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley - As an active user of `Azure` tag, I am so glad that you brought that up. One more thing I noticed is quite often these people plagiarize other people's answer and pass them as their own. A few of them got banned but resorted back to their old tactics once the ban is lifted. My guess is that Microsoft pays them based on the quantity of the answers and not the quality. I used to downvote their answers but stopped doing it as that resulted in no improvement. I am now resorting to flagging these answers.

Comment: Funny enough, this is a very common theme on their own forums too.  I haven't even messed with Azure stuff on here and I know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: This is not the first time this has come up. Related meta question (despite the title): *[Is it legitimate to mark (almost) all of your answers as "community wiki"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416882/is-it-legitimate-to-mark-almost-all-of-your-answers-as-community-wiki#comment901596_416882)*. Presumably it is Microsoft contractors with a similar role. And similar (terse) answer structure (possibly due to some particular incentives, like quantity).

Comment: I don't understand why Microsoft hasn't replaced this type of "support" staff with bots. Bots would probably be more helpful and wouldn't cost nearly as much. It's not as if Microsoft don't have a [platform or framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) to build such bots...

Comment: As for these accounts and their "answers", my suggestion is to nuke from orbit. While Stack Overflow has numerous quality problems, this one should be relatively simple to address: pull all accounts with the suffix "-MSFT", scan a sample of answers from each account for quality, if those answers are poor blow that account away. Wash, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Downvoting will at least rate-limit their posting if they aren't getting enough upvotes to offset.  And make it easier for tools to detect patterns like account names that consistently get significant downvotes, in case anyone gets around to doing something about it.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Not sure I understand this: `Downvoting will at least rate-limit their posting if they aren't getting enough upvotes to offset.`. Does the system automatically stops users from posting answers if their answers are consistently downvoted?

Comment: @IanKemp - FWIW, These users have `-MT` in their name (and not `-MSFT`). I believe it stands for Mindtree which is a big IT services company here in India and does a lot of business with Microsoft.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Yes.  Usually people run into the question ban when their posts are mostly downvoted, but Martijn's answer on [If someone keeps downvoting my old answers can I be answer banned?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386538) says "The answer ban is not going to kick in here ..." - phrasing which implies there is an automatic answer ban that can apply in other cases.  Also [What information can I use to determine which answers need improving in order to lift an answer ban?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411201) confirms there's an answer ban. The tag is [post-ban] not [question-ban]

Comment: There is absolutely an answer ban similar to the question ban, it's just a little less common to be affected by it.

Comment: Also now [one with an "MSFT_" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19153814/msft-fvn) ([deleted junk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077661/))

Comment: FWIW: a spot check of the last couple of answers by the author of those answers shows they dropped the `-MT` (or `-MSFT`) and give decent answers, for which I can't quickly find plagiarism. In other words: this meta seems to have fulfilled its purpose!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you can do are the usual things: downvote bad answers, flag answers as Very Low Quality or Not An Answer where applicable and/or leave a comment pointing out why the answer is wrong or bad.

If there is a pattern that a user or group of users repeatedly post such bad answers, collect examples and flag for moderator attention. A moderator can then investigate and send the user(s) a message when they think it's appropriate and escalate to the Stack Exchange employees if they think that Microsoft themselves should somehow be contacted about this issue.

Example of a mod flag (marked helpful) I sent two years ago:

> This looks to be an official Microsoft support account, but they keep answer low quality questions like these and do that often with barely more than a link, e.g. answer1, answer2 images of code answer3 and other low-quality contributions. Could you please nudge them to adhere to the quality standards?

And a helpful flag sent two weeks ago (Oct 2022):

> This user could benefit from a message about their prose. They use "Hi  and thanks for your question/reaching out" to start most of their answers, as well as adding fluff as "hope that helps"/ "let me know if you need more assistance" etc at the bottom. Eg [link] [link] etc. Typical MSFT help desk behaviour.

I redacted the links to the answers to prevent the meta-effect.

Comment: Note that NAA or VLQ flags are *not* appropriate for most the example images in this meta question; they at least look like answers, and aren't purely link only.  [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552), and more recent comments from moderators on [Not-an-answer flag declined on an answer ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409213) - they seem to only want NAA / VLQ on things that can be handled quickly and obviously, without a judgement call on whether it's above some threshold of minimum quality, or any subject-matter knowledge.

Comment: Do Microsoft use ChatGPT internally to generate answers?

Answer (score -49):

> What other actions should I be taking?

On top of downvoting, if you feel the need "Flag as not an answer" or simply tell them they're answer is of low quality and/or if they're breaking SO etiquette, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72539280/495455

---

My two cents; I typically ignore them as there's two sides to the coin here and it levels out...

Most people like you see their posts as a training ground for new MSFT Support Engineers and a way for Microsoft to get eyeballs on their documentation. Meh.

On the other side of the coin Microsoft employees have access to an internal Database of Customer Service Requests (SRs). The system is called Visual Knowledge Base or VKB for short. Microsoft Content Strategists go through the SR cases and when they see lots of engineers referencing a particular SR with a good solution they turn it into a SOX: Solution Object. Finally the SOX's get turned in KB articles. So more often than not the MS Engineers will do internal search and sometimes provide information you'd have to pay to raise a support case.

Comment: I'm not following "the other side of the coin". It's great that they *could* be giving high quality answers, but the problem is that they *are* giving low quality answers. The former don't make the latter any better.

Comment: That's subjective. The answer I've given is objective, fight Microsoft all you want.

Comment: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/525036) – this does not apply here

Comment: @DidierL it does it you are only linking to the documentation.

Comment: *"Microsoft employee's have access to an internal Database of Customer Service Requests (SRs)"* - That is a handy tool for troubleshooting. However, Stack Overflow is not a discussion and support forum. Having vendor-appointed experts answer questions about their own products and services can be a great thing, but if MS is using SO as a support forum or writing answers we would consider to be LQ from any other user... we absolutely do not want either of those things.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you seem to be confusing "the truth" with the idea that the bad behavior is a necessary prerequisite to obtain the (alleged) good behavior, which of course isn't objectively true. Many of our contributors are capable of posting good answers without also posting stupid junk as if their paycheck depended on it. We can't demand good answers from Microsoft (and indeed, many of us gave up on that hope completely many, many years ago) but we _can_ demand them to not sabotage the site.

Comment: *"Most people like you see their posts as a training ground for new MSFT Support Engineers and a way for Microsoft to get eyeballs on their documentation"* - What on earth do you base this assertion on?